# Not getting the right value with numpy polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, polynomials, data-fitting

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a = np.ndarray((2,8))

a[0] = [0,10,21.5,25.2,70,89,112,150] # row for all X values
a[1] = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35] # row for all Y values


#Value by curve fitting - 7th order polynomial            
trend = np.polyfit(a[0], a[1], 7)
trendpoly = np.poly1d(trend) #Values of the coefficients of 5th order polynomial
plt.plot(a[0],trendpoly(a[0]))
plt.plot(a[0],a[1])

Y4 = trendpoly(100)
plt.scatter(100,Y4)

print(Y4)
```

The results plot looks like this - a perfect fit with data. Two overlapping curves of the data and the curve fit, with a scatter point showing the value at X = 100 which is way off from the curve fit

[image: Two overlapping curves of the data and the curve fit, with a scatter point showing the value at X = 100 which is way off from the curve fit]

What's going wrong here? why is the value of trendpoly(100) not coherent with the curve fit?

Comment: The problem is that you are only plotting few points and lines between them. If you do something like 
`b = np.arange(0,155,5) plt.scatter(b,trendpoly(b)) plt.scatter(a[0], a[1])`
you will see the overfit effect outside your given points.

Comment: Thank you I checked it that way and I can see all the points with overfit effects. I'd like to ask you the same question that I asked another answerer. Really appreciate your help. So, I had tried a 5th order polynomial which gives a more reasonable value but then the trend curve doesn't fit as well with the data curve..so I used the 7th order polynomial which fits very well at the data points not with the linspace. Scientifically, which curve fit should I trust then? And if I hadn't needed X = 100 I wouldn't have come across this issue. Is there a way to know if we are over fitting data?

Comment: Depending on your final objective, you should learn about bias-variance tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem of [overfitting](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/overfitting.asp).

The more you set the order of the polynomial, more will be the overfitting. 
Try with an order of 3 or less to observe the change.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried with a 5th order polynomial which gives a more reasonable value but then the trend curve doesn't fit as well with the data curve..so I used the 7th order polynomial which fits very well. Scientifically, which curve fit should I trust then? And if I hadn't needed X = 100 I wouldn't have come across this issue. Is there a way to know if we are over fitting data? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. One way to identify this is by [Regularization](https://www.steveklosterman.com/over-under/)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's quite relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the whole polynomial you have fit and scatter your data points

```
trend = np.polyfit(a[0], a[1], 7)
x_line = np.linspace(0,150,1000)
fit = np.polyval(trend, x_line)
plt.scatter(a[0], a[1])
plt.plot(x_line, fit)
```

you will likely see a wildly ocillating curve that ocillates around your data-points. Ways to determine the degree of your fitting polynomial are 1) looking at what kind of function you expect your data to follow. 2) trying out different polynomial degrees until you get a fit that doesn't oscillate unreasonably much.

If you have n data points, a polynomial of degree >= n-1 will intercept every data point perfectly, but will be far off from your curve between the data-points.

If you expect your data to follow some non-polynomial function like log(x) or exp(x)  (or maybe a * sqrt(b * x) in this case), you could look into scipy.curve_fit.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is quite helpful.